# tools to use to measure request speed and database speed

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, database

I am writing up a thesis for my web/database project and I just have a couple of questions on knowing which tool is best to use to measure web and database speed. I am using php/jquery/html/mysqli

Question 1: Is it best to use Firebug to test how long each request takes in firefox? If so is it ideal to show a screenshot of every request which has taken place in a page or is it best to show all the requests at once. In other words do you want to see the full time of all the requests or each and every individual request.

Question 2: When testing database speed as I have a database in phpmyadmin, what is best tool to use in order to measure speed of database and what are you most interested in seeing when view speed of database. Is it how long it takes a query to run, or table to how up, inserting data? etc.

Thank You

Comment: You want to do **one** request and take that as a proper data for the speed of your website in a thesis? And put a screenshot of a firebug as your source? Seriously?

Comment: @Ranty that is why I am asking you experts ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test your project you need to emulate different load volume and provide averaged values of response times.

It would be best if you could generate enough load to reach failure point multiple times. It can be maximum allowed simultaneous database connections or anything similar that will case some requests to fail. That will be your maximum load.

For volumes between no and maximum you need to do breakpoints and test your system on them. For each breakpoint you need to generate thousands of tries so you could remove extremums and calculate average values.

For example, if your system starts encountering failures at 200 simultaneous requests, you can test it at 1, 25, 50, 100, 150 requests breakpoints. Also you need to pick the amount of tries for each breakpoint, let's say you'll pick 10000. Then you do 10000 lone requests, 10000 requests consisting of 25 simultaneous calls, then of 50 calls, etc.

On top of that you will need different graphs to show the increase of reply time and your overall system behaviour. You then will need to explain why load times increase and provide ways to optimize both your software and hardware in order to make your system capable of dealing with bigger load.

Apart from simultaneous (parallel) requests, you might want to also consider testing on how your system will behave on different load of consecutive requests.

That's how it should look like in general. I'm sure there is software to do such kind of analysis, but you could write your own simple scripts that will generate load. In later case I'm sure that will be a big plus for your thesis if you will be able to provide enough data to show that your load generating software works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I like [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/).. I dont know if there's an open source (free?) software like that one. However theres a free version of new relic.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For the php proccesses and their load times I like to use `xDebug` with `KCacheGrind` or `WinCacheGrind`.

From xDebug site:

> Xdebug's built-in profiler allows you to find bottlenecks in your script and visualize those with an external tool such as KCacheGrind or WinCacheGrind.

more info: [xDebug Docs](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)